# Python NotImplementedError: pool objects cannot be passed between processes

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool

I'm trying to deliver work when a page is appended to the pages list, but my code output returns a NotImplementedError. Here is the code with what I'm trying to do:

**Code:**

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, current_process
import time
import random
import copy_reg
import types
import threading


class PageControler(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.nProcess = 3
        self.pages = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
        self.manageWork()


    def manageWork(self):

        self.pool = Pool(processes=self.nProcess)

        time.sleep(2)
        work_queue = threading.Thread(target=self.modifyQueue)
        work_queue.start()

        #pool.close()
        #pool.join()

    def deliverWork(self):    
        if self.pages != []:
            pag = self.pages.pop()
            self.pool.apply_async(self.myFun)


    def modifyQueue(self):
        t = time.time()
        while (time.time()-t) < 10:
            time.sleep(1)
            self.pages.append(99)
            print self.pages
            self.deliverWork()

    def myFun(self):
        time.sleep(2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    def _pickle_method(m):
        if m.im_self is None:
            return getattr, (m.im_class, m.im_func.func_name)
        else:
            return getattr, (m.im_self, m.im_func.func_name)

    copy_reg.pickle(types.MethodType, _pickle_method)

    PageControler()
```

**Output:**

```
NotImplementedError: pool objects cannot be passed between processes or pickled
```

It's any way to pass the pool object between the processes ?

**Edit:**

I'm using Python 2.6

Comment: python 2.7, I suppose?

Comment: Python 2.6, but I've been reading and python 2.7 have the same problem.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

In order to pickle the instance method you're trying to pass to the `Pool`, Python needs to pickle the entire `PageControler` object, including its instance variables. One of those instance variables is the `Pool` object itself, and `Pool` objects can't be pickled, hence the error. You can work around this by implementing [`__getstate__`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/pickle.html#object.__getstate__) on the object, and using that to remove the `pool` object from the instance prior to pickling:

```
class PageControler(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.nProcess = 3
        self.pages = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
        self.manageWork()


    def manageWork(self):

        self.pool = Pool(processes=self.nProcess)

        time.sleep(2)
        work_queue = threading.Thread(target=self.modifyQueue)
        work_queue.start()

        #pool.close()
        #pool.join()

    def deliverWork(self):    
        if self.pages != []:
            pag = self.pages.pop()
            self.pool.apply_async(self.myFun)


    def modifyQueue(self):
        t = time.time()
        while (time.time()-t) < 10:
            time.sleep(1)
            self.pages.append(99)
            print self.pages
            self.deliverWork()

    def myFun(self):
        time.sleep(2)

    def __getstate__(self):
        self_dict = self.__dict__.copy()
        del self_dict['pool']
        return self_dict

    def __setstate__(self, state):
        self.__dict__.update(state)
```

`__getstate__` is always called prior to pickling an object, and allow you to specify exactly which pieces of the object's state should actually be pickled. Then upon unpickling, [`__setstate__(state)`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/pickle.html#object.__setstate__) will be called if its implemented (it is in our case), or if it's not, the `dict` returned by `__getstate__` will be used as the `__dict__` for the unpickled instance. In the above example, we're explicitly setting `__dict__` to the `dict` we returned in `__getstate__`, but we could have just not implemented `__setstate__` and gotten the same effect.

Comment: This is a very nice answer and helped solve my issue. It led me to this in Python3, which may be useful to others: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#object.__getstate__

Comment: This is awesome! You rock @dano! Thanks

Comment: Wow, what a good answer.  I now understand what's been happening for the last two hours.  Thanks @dano

Comment: This solution solved my problem. It looks just like @transient in JAVA.

Answer (score 2):

Dano's answer is a good approach if you must pass the entire object to the process. In your case, the function you are passing to pool has no requirement for a reference to the class instance. So an alternative may be to make the function a static method using the `@staticmethod` decorator. If the function does require reference to one or two class member variables these could be passed in as arguments for read only variables, and updated in a callback if a write is required also (of course, you will need to do this if you want to update the local class instance in any case).

For example:

```
Class A(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self._pool = multiprocessing.Pool(1)
        self.member_variable = 1

    @staticmethod
    def MyFunc(variable):
        variable += 1
        return variable

    def Callback(self, return_val):
        self.member_variable = return_val

    def CallFuncAsync(self):
        pool.apply_async(self.MyFunc, (self.member_variable,), callback=self.Callback)
```