# How to reuse workers from Pool for a genetic algorithm

Tags: python, python-2.7, parallel-processing, genetic-algorithm, python-multiprocessing

I had a previous related question on this problem: [Parallelize for loop in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40402279/parallelize-for-loop-in-python)

I have a genetic algorithm which I'm trying to speed up by parallelizing the evaluation function. The GA is a class and the code looks something like this:

```
copy_reg.pickle(types.MethodType,lambda method: (getattr, (method.im_self, method.im_func.__name__)),getattr) 

class GA:

    ...
    ...

    def evaluation(self):
        self.scores = Pool(processes=nprocs).map(self.costly_function,self.population)

    def run(self):
        self.initial_population()
        self.evaluation()
        while self.Gen > i:
            self.select()
            self.crossover()
            self.mutation()
            self.evaluation()
            i += 1
```

This gives the right result compared to the sequential method but it is significantly slower. My guess is that this is because I'm creating a new group of process workers for each generation inside the while loop in the function `evaluation`. Is there a way of reusing the workers so I can achieve a speed up?

Comment: What is nprocs set to? Is `self.costly_function` 'costly' in terms of CPU, memory, IO or something else?

Comment: It is set to 4 and `costly_function` is costly in terms of CPU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by adding the function below which I got from https://stackoverflow.com/a/25385582/4759898

```
def __getstate__(self):
    self_dict = self.__dict__.copy()
    del self_dict['pool']
    return self_dict

def __setstate__(self, state):
    self.__dict__.update(state)
```